# How to control header background color in a table view with model?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtableview, qtstylesheets

The code creates a single `QTableView` assigned to `QAbstractTableModel`:

[image]

Questions: 
1. How to change the header background color to blue?
2. How to change the lower portion of the TableView (currently white) to orange.

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)      

        self.items=['One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven']

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):   
        return len(self.items)
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)):
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        item=str(self.items[index.row()])

        if role==QtCore.Qt.UserRole:
            return item

        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return item

        if role==QtCore.Qt.TextColorRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.white))

        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            if index.row()%2:
                return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.gray))
            else:
                return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.darkGray))

        if role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return (QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

    def headerData(self, column, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return (QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.blue)) 

        if role == QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.red))
            elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
                return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.green))

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            return QtCore.QString('Horizont Column')

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            return QtCore.QString('Vertical Column')

        if role == QtCore.Qt.FontRole:
            return QtGui.QFont('Times', pointSize=5, weight=-1, italic=True)


class TableView(QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TableView, self).__init__(parent)

        self.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch) 

        myModel=TableModel()
        self.setModel(myModel)      

view=TableView()
view.show()   
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second question:

`QTableView` is a `QFrame`, you should change color of whole frame, but of course next code:

```
QFrame
{
  background-color:yellow
}
```

will change background color of many other widgets, so it is not a solution. To apply this property only to your specific tableview just set some object name to it with

```
tableView->setObjectName("myFrame");
```

and use:

```
#myFrame
{
  background-color:yellow
}
```

For header item color use next `stylesheet`:

```
QHeaderView::section
{
  background-color:blue
}
```

So result will be:

[image]

As you can see, sections have blue color and other area of `QTableView` has yellow color which is separate from color of model data

Comment: Terrific! Thanks! I still would like to know how to achieve the same using  model.